# ODBC Connector Bitness Issue (I think) on Windows Server 2012

Tags: mysql, odbc

I have a 32-bit application that uses a UDL file to connect to a mySQL database on a different host.  This 32-bit EXE is running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM. There was a HDD failure and I'm reconfiguring the system to connect to the database, so I know this configuration should not be so troublesome.

A snapshot of what is true:

- MySQL ODBC Connector (32-bit) 8.0.23 is installed.
- I created the connection with a unique DSN in the 32-bit ODBC admin panel.
- Testing the connection through the 32-bit admin panel works fine (I can see the schema, etc.).

Here's where things start getting fishy:

- When I open the UDL file my application uses to start the connection, the 32-bit DSNs don't show up. If I type them in manually, I get the 'architecture mismatch' error that everyone seems to agree actually means 'bitness mismatch' (If I create a 64-bit DSN, they show up and ping the DB no problem.)
- I found this trick to open the UDL file using the 32-bit ODBC driver:

> OLEDB is very similar in that there is a 32 bit version and a 64 bit version of the providers.  The easiest way to configure and OLEDB data source is to create an .UDL file on the operating system.  By double clicking on the .UDL file you will see the OLEDB providers for the 64 bit side of the operating system presented in the Data Link Properties dialog.  To get to the 32 bit version of the OLEDB providers you need to execute the following command line from a command shell.

**C:\Windows\syswow64\rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll",OpenDSLFile C:\test.udl**

...And that works! I can see the 32-bit named connections. The 'Test Connection' button produces happy output. But when I run my application, it does not connect using the DSN/credentials of the UDL file. It *behaves* like it is still trying to call the 64-bit version of the ODBC driver.

If my assumptions are correct, then how do I get my EXE to prioritize using the correct (x86) 32-bit **oledb32.dll**? Compatibility mode didn't fix my issue and I've run out of "clever" ideas to try.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!